# Setting up a hidden service

Tags: onion-services, configuration

I am trying to set up my own hidden service following this tutorial:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-hidden-service-tor-site-set-anonymous-website-server/

I have, however, recognized a problem when I got to the point where I have to edit torrc file, which in my case is blank. I thought it's a tor system file, so it ought to be somewhere else, I searched for it using windows search, came back with only one result, the blank one. Can anyone tell me how to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter. The old `torrc` file contents were moved to `torrc-defaults` file (in the same folder), but you should be able to write your hidden service configuration in the blank `torrc` file without a problem nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee you Torrc is there. If you can't navigate to it graphically, do `nano /etc/tor/torrc` in a terminal- it should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

become a hosting a hidden service is much Risk than just browing it / become a relay , actually using Orbot / OnionShare that can everybody without PhD degree in computerSecience still canbe a GEEK

however , dont use speical Keywork likes Co-VeeWMD_Cryto or OmiconMarket that may getting filtering by UTM/NGFW etc , however we suggest all the Geek Using SATCOM(starLink)/remore rural location (2/3G only/No 4/5G signal) to setup HiddenService to avoid your frontDoor breakthough by Authority >_< escept Food deilivery